# how to display the dob dd mm yyyy values from database to let the users edit it

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if I asked the question properly or not..

Well I am having a form where I have a dob field and dd mm yyyy are taken from users with 3 textfields..
and I took those values and inserted into the db like dis..

```
$dob=$_POST('yyyy')+"-"+$_POST('mm')+"-"+$_POST('dd');
(Insert bla bla bla)

DOB <input type="text" name="dd">

<input type="text" name="mm">

<input type="text" name="yyyy">
```

Now I am having another form where I'm letting the users edit their info including the dob and update those..

Now I want to show their current dob in the editinfo page where 3 text fields will be same and i want to display the  user's dob date in dd, dob month in mm,and dob year in yyyy field coming from database.
Just like we return the value in a text field like

```
<input type="text' value="<?php echo $name;?>
```

I want to do the same..but can't return the value of $dob because it will surely return in yyyy-mm-dd.I want the each value to be displayed in separate fields as I mentioned..

Any help will be deeply appreciated.. Thank you..!!!

Comment: After get the value of dob from database explode it by - and  show it in three text filed. At the time of saving implode it by - and save it.

Comment: use `date()`. I have an old function i used to use 

`function Datify($Date){
return date('jS F Y \a\t H:i:s', strtotime($Date));
}`

Comment: `$_POST()`? is this a typo? `$_POST` is an array btw not a function, its `$_POST['index_here']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explode function to get each values. As you know the returning result from mysql will be in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format .

for example '2015-04-01' is the value . then

```
<?php
 $date = '2015-04-01';
 $splited_date_array = explode('-',$date);
 $year = $splited_date_array[0];
 $month = $splited_date_array[1];
 $day = $splited_date_array[2];
?>
```

Comment: you are welcome. you can select the answer as correct